# jQuery JavaScript Detect object in view / window

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, this may have been asked dozens of times over. But I'm not exactly sure what technique or term I would have to search for in order to find out more information on this.

What I have is an Unordered list of Elements. Each one acting as a screen on a project I am working on. Each element is the size of the browser window, so its more like a power point presentation then anything if I were to describe it in any sense of the logic I have here. So what I am trying to do is find out when any particular slide is active in the view. One I have a few images I would like to load only when the view is active. But what I am really looking for is to highlight the navigation according to the slide I am on. The navigation is a fixed element so its always on the screen while everything else just floats on in, in a matter of speaking. Another reason I need this is, the navigation doesn't come into effect until the second slide. So I need a way to trigger the navigation into displaying itself only when every slide other than the first one is in view, and I will remove it when the first slide is in the view.

Hopefully I made some sense on this, anyone have any idea's?

Comment: Can you show some code for what you do to switch between the slides?

Comment: Right now I have it based off the scroll bar position but I also use a button and trigger scrollTop() to go to the top of the element. The ultimate goal is to some how mimic something like http://www.numarkns6.com/#!home

Comment: as for code otherwise, the html is literally a ul/li combination nothing more nothing less, with the CSS defining the sizing. Still in the very early stage of dev, getting it to scroll to a spot no problem, finding out if its there to fire something else off whole different thing in my eyes currently.

Comment: All the content from that example is loaded up front.

Comment: Yes, the loading of the images as I mentioned is one part, though the bigger part I mention the whole notion for is copying the menu when I scroll down the page, either with the wheel on my mouse, scrolling with the arrow on the scroller or clicking a menu item, the item highlights, also just recently noticed that it changes the URL too but thats a mute point here for the moment. Either way, when the slide is active in the screen different things happen around that slide being active..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like adding a class to the element in view when it enters view, removing all other instances of the same class when you put it in view.

something like

```
$('.active').removeClass('e_active');
$(this).addClass('e_active');
```

would enable you to find the current active element. alternatively if you are using element id's to find the element, you could do

```
$('#element').addClass('e_active')
```

where '#element' is the active element

if you are clicking elements to get the ID, you could use something like this:

HTML:

```
<ul class="slides">
  <li id="elem1" class="e_active">content1</li>
  <li id="elem2">content2</li>
  <li id="elem3">content3</li>
  <li id="elem4">content4</li>
</ul>

<ul class="nav">
  <li data-link="elem1">Link1</li>
  <li data-link="elem2">Link2</li>
  <li data-link="elem3">Link3</li>
  <li data-link="elem4">Link4</li>
</ul>
```

then with the script you could do something like this:

```
$('li', '.nav').click(function(){
  elem = $(this).data('link');
  $('.e_active').removeClass('e_active');
  $('#'+elem, '.slides').addClass('e_active');
})
```

which would enable you to simply use `.e_active` in your stylesheet and any jquery code to alter the active element.

Of course, if you are doing it on scroll or keypress, the method is the same, you just need to attach the function to the relavent event handler.

also, with your 'navigation' issue, you just need to use `$('.nav').hide()` when the element id for the first slide also has the class `e_active` and `$('.nav').show()` it when it doesn't, adding and removing a class like `nav_hidden` from the nav element so it doesn't repeatedly show it.

Comment: This part Im already understanding of.. What I am trying to detect is if the one that will be tagged as e_active in your example.. is actually being viewed at the time. Say if I scrolled down the page to that one specifically. I'd like the navigation to follow suit with the scroll, thats what I am trying to figure out.

Comment: By this method, the one tagged `e_active` would be the active one in view, and the class would be removed when it isn't in view.

By they way, you do realise that it would be easier to simply attach the CSS `position: fixed` to the navigation and it would scroll with the page.

Like I said, if you want to use scroll or keypress, you just need to apply the code to the relevant event handlers... I'll edit my answer to give an example.

Comment: I swear I edited this to include examples of scroll and keypress event handlers, I did it on my phone but it mustn't have sent it to the server :O